# How to create an object specific list that doesn't empty itself when called more than once

Tags: python, class, pycharm

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Lte.png)

in init I declare two list variables that are called `nlist` and `rlist`.

Then in method `add_neighour` I am appending object (router2) named `router2.__routername` to the list of object called `self.nlist`.

```
class Router:

    def __init__(self, routername):

        self.__routername = routername

        self.nlist = []
        self.rlist = []

    def print_info(self):

        print(self.nlist)

        print("  ", self.__routername, sep="")
        print("    N: ", ", ".join(sorted(self.nlist)), sep="")
        print("    R: ", ", ".join(sorted(self.rlist)), sep="")

    def add_neighbour(self, router2):
        self.nlist.append(router2.__routername)

        print(self.nlist)
```

I'm calling the code inside the while True that waits for a specific commmand:

Command P is for printing info

```
    if command == "P":
        routername = input("Enter router name: ")

        if routername not in mydict:
            print("Router was not found.")
        else:
            router = Router(routername)
            router.print_info()
```

Command C is for chaining two routers together. (for example appending router2s name `router2.__routername` to the neighbour list `self.nlist` of router1.

This happens `class Router` inside the method `add_neighbour` that takes another router as parameter.

```
    elif command == "C":
        router1 = input("Enter 1st router: ")
        router2 = input("Enter 2nd router: ")

        router1 = Router(router1)
        router2 = Router(router2)

        router1.add_neighbour(router2)
        router2.add_neighbour(router1)
```

The appending goes fine and when I `print(self.nlist)` at the end it shows up that the list has been updated with the appended element I wanted. However, when calling the `print_info` function and trying to print the `sorted(self.nlist)` It prints an empty list.

I have no clue why. Should I declare the object specific list in a different way/place?

or

append values to the list differently?

**my goal is to:** succesfully print `self.nlist` inside the `print_info` method. Succesfully printing meaning that it prints something else than an empty list.

I tried looking for answers from several posts. Sorry if this post is duplicate and horribly written.

**The whole code: (in progress as you can see...)**

```
class Router:

    def __init__(self, routername):

        self.__routername = routername

        self.nlist = []
        self.rlist = []

    def print_info(self):

        print(self.nlist)

        print("  ", self.__routername, sep="")
        print("    N: ", ", ".join(sorted(self.nlist)), sep="")
        print("    R: ", ", ".join(sorted(self.rlist)), sep="")

    def add_neighbour(self, router2):
        self.nlist.append(router2.__routername)

        print(self.nlist)


def main():
    mydict = {}

    routerfile = input("Network file: ")

    while True:
        command = input("> ")
        command = command.upper()

        if command == "P":
            routername = input("Enter router name: ")

            if routername not in mydict:
                print("Router was not found.")
            else:
                router = Router(routername)
                router.print_info()


            pass

        elif command == "PA":
            pass

        elif command == "S":
            pass

        elif command == "C":
            router1 = input("Enter 1st router: ")
            router2 = input("Enter 2nd router: ")

            router1 = Router(router1)
            router2 = Router(router2)

            router1.add_neighbour(router2)
            router2.add_neighbour(router1)

            pass

        elif command == "RR":
            pass

        elif command == "NR":
            routername = input("Enter a new name: ")
            router = Router(routername)
            if routername not in mydict:
                mydict[routername] = router
            else:
                print("Name is taken.")

            pass

        elif command == "NN":
            pass

        elif command == "Q":
            print("Simulator closes.")
            return

        else:
            print("Erroneous command!")
            print("Enter one of these commands:")
            print("NR (new router)")
            print("P (print)")  
            print("C (connect)")
            print("NN (new network)")
            print("PA (print all)")
            print("S (send routing tables)")
            print("RR (route request)")
            print("Q (quit)")

main()
```

Comment: Please show how you are calling this code, with both the add_neighbour and print_info calls.

Comment: Note also, this code as you have posted it would give an AttributeError in add_neighbour, because `__routername` will be mangled due to the double-underscore. Please show actual code.

Comment: All of your commands are creating entirely new `Router` objects, each with an initially empty `nlist`.  Of course that prints out as empty - the objects to which you previously added neighbors have long since been discarded.